# How can I do a telnet to a local HTTP server?

Tags: c, http, server, telnet

I know how to do it to a remote server, it would be like:

```
telnet www.esqsoft.globalservers.com 80
```

But I don't know to a local server (written in C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply substitute the hostname into the url, for example for a computer on your network with the hostname "LivingRoom", use the command
`telnet LivingRoom 80`.
For a server on own computer, simply use `telnet localhost 80`.

Comment: Also, don't forget that you can always telnet to an IP address, i.e. telnet 192.168.1.10 80, if you don't have a DNS name available.